# How to create DataTable for ColumnChart by JSON object?

Tags: json, visualization

I'm trying to create a DataTable, with JSON as parameter, for a ColumnChart from the Google visualization api.

I generated the following JSON object:

```
{
    "cols": [
        {"id":"date", "label":"date","pattern":"", "type":"date"},
        {"id":"jobsonstatus", "label":"jobsonstatus", "pattern":"", "type":"number"}
    ],
    "rows": [
        {
            "c": [
                {"v": "01-02-2013", "f": null},
                {"v": 128, "f": null}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v": "08-02-2013", "f": null},
                {"v": 185, "f": null}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v": "15-02-2013", "f": null},
                {"v": 142, "f": null}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v": "22-02-2013", "f": null},
                {"v": 86, "f": null}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What's wrong with this?

Maybe it's something else. The rest of the code is:

```
    var chart;      //The chart
var options;    //The options for the chart
var data;       //The data inside the chart

//This function will set up the actual chart but doesn't draw it.           
function init(){
    chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    options = {
        width:600, height:450,      
        legend: {'position': 'top'},
        allowHtml: true
    };                      
}

function changeData(dataPar){
    data = new google.visualization.DataTable(dataPar);
    drawChart();                  
}

function drawChart(){   
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

The JSON object is thrown in the function changeData().

And i've got this in the ajax part:

```
    dataType: "json",       
    success: function(res, textStatus, jqXHR){
       changeData(res);
    }
```

I'm getting an error with a red background:

> a[dc] is not a function

Does anybody know what's going wrong and what should be the solution?

Comment: I found out that the "null" in the json object has to be null without the quotes. But now I get a new error: 

b[ya] is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, I figured it out myself.

In the cols I had set the type of the column "date" to date but it had to be a string because the given value is a string.

So if you get strange errors from the [google visualization charts](http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam) then you probably have an error in your json part wich seems to be valid by [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/).

My suggestion to debug the json part is to first make a dummy DataTable by using the functions addColumn() and addRows() and then do

```
console.log([DataTable var].toJSON()).
```

Compare this output with the JSON you've created with your previous script and debug.

I've got the following JSON object:

```
{
    "cols": [
        {"id": "date", "label": "date","pattern": "","type": "string"},
        {"id": "newjobs","label": "newjobs","pattern": "","type": "number"}
    ],
    "rows": [
        {"c": [
                {"v": "01-02-2013","f": null},
                {"v": 132,"f": null}
            ]},
        {"c": [
                {"v": "08-02-2013","f": null},
                {"v": 78,"f": null}
            ]},
        {"c": [
                {"v": "15-02-2013","f": null},
                {"v": 105,"f": null}
            ]
        },
        {"c": [
                {"v": "22-02-2013","f": null},
                {"v": 8,"f": null}
            ]}
    ]
}
```